# How do I find my DOMAIN.onmicrosoft.com domain for Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I want to add another user to my company's Azure account. For now, we have not linked it to our company's domain, so we are advised to  use an account like `user@DOMAIN.onmicrosoft.com`.

How do I learn that `DOMAIN` value? I tried my own second-level domain (e.g. `X` in `X.com`, where our emails have the form `user@X.com`). But trying to add `user@X.onmicrosoft.com` still gives me the error message "X.onmicrosoft.com is not a verified domain name in this directory."

How do I sign up a new user to Azure under `???.onmicrosoft.com`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find your Azure Active Directory tenant name:

- Go to the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com)
- Navigate to `Azure Active Directory`
- Find your tenant name on the Overview page (on the top left)

[image: AAD tenant name]

And to add a user follow the steps above, and then:

- Navigate to `Users`
- Click `New user`