# Programmatically obtaining Azure Active Directory tenant name from ID

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

How can I get an AAD tenant name (not necessarily mine), from a GUID? This would be via the REST API ideally, but the Azure CLI/Powershell works too.

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004819/how-do-i-find-my-domain-onmicrosoft-com-domain-for-azure), but it requires going to the Azure Portal.

There are also plenty of links here and elsewhere on obtaining the tenant ID from the name, but I'm going in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the tenant name (and some other details) for the signed-in user by calling the /organization endpoint in MS Graph API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organization-get?view=graph-rest-1.0.

Request: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization`

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 411

{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#organization",
  "value": [
    {
      "assignedPlans": [
        {
          "assignedDateTime": "datetime-value",
          "capabilityStatus": "capabilityStatus-value",
          "service": "service-value",
          "servicePlanId": "servicePlanId-value"
        }
      ],
      "businessPhones": [
        "businessPhones-value"
      ],
      "city": "city-value",
      "country": "country-value",
      "countryLetterCode": "countryLetterCode-value",
      "displayName": "displayName-value"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if it's possible to do the same for an arbitrary ID? Ie, not just the logged-in user's.

Comment: As far as I know no.

Answer (score 0):

you can get other tenant information using this graph api endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/tenantRelationships/findTenantInformationByTenantId(tenantId='{GUID}')
```

E.g.,

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/tenantRelationships/findTenantInformationByTenantId(tenantId='9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad')
```

Graph permission required: `CrossTenantInformation.ReadBasic.All`